# What programs allow this kind of data entry?

Tags: modeling

I am looking for a program (preferably standalone, non-web) which allows generic information modelling. By the latter, I mean the creation of entity and relationship types, and their instances. A few examples will clarify what I mean.

With a blank canvas, I'd like to define the entities Computer, Person, Company, University, City.. and the relationships Founded, Designed, Was Born In, Attended. Having defined this information model "schema", I could then data input "Bill Gates" as a Person, the "University of Washington" as a University, "Microsoft" as a company, and then add the relationships "Bill Gates" Founded "Microsoft", etc..

With a blank canvas, I'd like to define the Entity types "Person", "Property", "Deed", "Notary" and the relationships "Owns", "Sells", "Appears Before", and so no. Such information modelling would allow specific scenarios of historic events surrounding property being sold/bought to be modeled.

Similarly I would like to be able to define a schema tailored to genealogical trees: Male, Female, Parent Of, City..

Once the data is entered, I would like to visualise everything via the free program yEd, which has great graph layout algorithms. Doing queries on the data would be nice, but at this stage, I'm only after a tool allowing easy data entry.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: I think the important question is what you'd like to do with all the data once you've collected it. For example, if you want to perform automatic inferences with prepositional logic, then conventional database management systems probably won't do; you'll need software for representing and reasoning with formal ontologies.

Comment: @JavaLaurence Please edit your Question to provide additional information and clarification, rather than posting as Comment.